# Arranging Windows/Applications via presets

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there any software for OS X that can automatically arrange a workspace according to a preset?

By some sort of shortcut, I would like to launch applications and then place them in a certain way (position, size). It would be great if different arrangements are possible for multiple displays, if they are plugged in.

Budget: Anything from free to $15 USD (preferably free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best option out there, but the application [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/) offers this functionality, albeit in a limited way.

It's possible to configure default window sizes and positions for applications. Saving a state and restoring the state can be done with keyboard shortcuts.

I would however have liked to see more options and different presets, even combined presets with multiple applications in one layout.